# can we combine laravel language files like validation.php to json?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

We can use json language files like ja.json from Laravel 5.4.
But i have still php language files like validation.php.
Is there a way to put inside json language files to share front end?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest in your controller you do something like:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/localization#retrieving-translation-strings

```
    public function convertLangToJson(){
        $lang = __('languagefilename');

        return response()->json($lang);
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much! how can I use that json file inside javascript?